# Anythingslider not working with a4j:ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, anythingslider

I am trying to use Anythingslider to slide between divs:

```
    <h:panelGroup id="preview" layout="block"
        style="float: left; margin-left: 100px;">

        <ul id="slider">
            <li><ui:include src="./preview/WelcomePreview.xhtml" /></li>
            <li><ui:include src="./preview/CardPreview.xhtml" /></li>
        </ul>

    </h:panelGroup>
```

But as soon if I include a table into the site, it won't work anymore. Please note that I am NOT including the table to the div which i include to the slider! It is outside of the list. Maybe it isn't the table which causes an error.

This is the html I try to include:

```
<rich:collapsiblePanel header="Title" switchType="client"
    expanded="false">

    <table style="table-layout: fixed;">
        <h:form>

            <tr>
                <td class="firstTD"><h:outputLabel value="Title: " /></td>
                <td><h:inputText id="title"
                        value="#{skinningBean.currentSkin.title}">
                        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="preview" />
                    </h:inputText></td>
            </tr>
        </h:form>
    </table>
</rich:collapsiblePanel>
```

**EDIT**

I already figured out, that this line of code produces the error:

```
    <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="titlePreview" />
```

Is there any way to make it work properly when using ajax?

**EDIT**

The first thing I did to avoid not finding the right javascript function was adding the jQuery noConflict tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
  $jq(function($){
  $('#slider1').anythingSlider();
});
</script>
```

Now my only problem is, that as soon as something is rendered on the page, the javascript isn't working anymore. I guess this is because the javascript is just loaded at page initialize. And the rendering doesn't load the full page beacuse of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`noConflict()` mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) is not being set properly. It should be done outside of the document ready function, like this:

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
$jq(function($){
  $('#slider1').anythingSlider();
});
```

---

I've never used a4j before, but from a quick look in the docs, I think the `oncomplete` attribute needs to be used to re-initialize the slider. Try something like this:

```
<a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="preview" oncomplete="initSlider()" />
```

Then change the javascript to this:

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

function initSlider() {
  $jq(function($){
    $('#slider1').anythingSlider();
  });
}
```

As I said, I'm clueless about using a4j, but this looks like it might work.

Comment: That update still isn't correct. You're calling the document ready function using the `$` instead of `jQuery`. After the `noConflict()` is called, the value of `$` is replaced with it's previous value (undefined or another library). Notice that in my answer, the function has a argument which is a `$` which is jQuery and can be used freely inside of the closure.

Comment: Okay thanks for this :)
But it will not change anything about getting my Slider converted back into a simple list after rendering something. I guess I won't find a way to get it work with a javascript tool

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, and actaully this is exactly what I want to achieve right now. Have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521029/reload-anythingslider-after-jsf-render?noredirect=1#comment21987264_15521029

Comment: Okay, wow... Ur code is working, mine is not :D Thanks a lot.
Post this also as an answer to my second question ;)

Comment: The only difference I see is the `event` attribute... I copied your `"keyup"` example above and in the other question I see `"change"`

Comment: And you initialize the jQuery variable outside the function. I guess that's the point, because it works with my change function :)