# Reload Anythingslider after JSF render

Tags: javascript, jsf, reload, anythingslider

I am trying to get my Anythingslider to be reloaded, after rendering the divs, which are in the list.

```
    <h:selectOneMenu id="dropdownDevice"
        value="#{skinningBean.currentDevice}" converter="SkinConverter">
        <f:selectItems value="#{skinningBean.myDevicesSI}" var="c"
            itemValue="#{c}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="preview" oncomplete="reloadSlider()" />

    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Note: the preview div is around the slider1 list

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function reloadSlider() {  
    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    $jq(function($){
      $jq('#slider1').anythingSlider();
    }); 
}  
</script>
```

But I get this error all the times (I tried more than this solution):

```
Error: TypeError: $jq(...).anythingSlider is not a function
```

After this, only the simple list elements are shown.
Any ideas how I can achieve reloading the slider?

Edit: I don't want the whole page to be reloaded, because the dropdown menu isn't the only component I'm rendering from

This is how I initialize anythingslider:

```
<script src="../js/jquery.anythingslider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/anythingslider.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
$jq(function($){
  $jq('#slider1').anythingSlider();
}); 
</script>
```

I just copied it and wrapped it with a function, so I can call it a second time.

Comment: How did you install anythingSlider then? The error is actually the whole answer at its own: it's not recognized as a function. Thus, you didn't install it properly.

Comment: Updated the question. And it's working when I laod the page the first time. But as soon as I render something it won't do like I want

Comment: Might be a RichFaces thing. What if you reference the script the proper JSF way by `<h:outputScript>`?

Comment: Exactly the same behavior. I didn't do it like that because I had some issues with JSColor before, which was not loading the images correctly when i used the h:outputScript. But it was when I used the normal script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem is that the `noConflict()` mode is being called more than once inside the function, move it outside:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
function reloadSlider() {  
    $jq(function($){
      $jq('#slider1').anythingSlider();
    }); 
}  
</script>
```